# Cannot run nbconvert command in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, nbconvert

I try to run a code using Jupyter Notebook, and then use nbconvert to export the created notebooks to pdf, but it does not work.

For reference my code is like this (But I don't think it is related to my code directly?):

```
# Import the necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nbconvert import PDFExporter
from nbformat import v4 as nbf

# Read the Excel file using Pandas
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('survey_responses.xlsx')

# Use a loop to iterate over the sheets and generate pie charts and PDF files for each one
for sheet_name in excel_file.sheet_names:
    # Read the sheet using Pandas
    df = excel_file.parse(sheet_name)
    
    # Create a new Jupyter notebook for the current sheet
    notebook = nbf.new_notebook()
    
    # Add a text cell to the Jupyter notebook
    text = 'The following pie charts show the results of the survey for Class {}.'.format(sheet_name)
    notebook['cells'].append(nbf.new_markdown_cell(text))
    
    # Use the subplots function to create a figure with multiple subplots
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(df.columns), ncols=1, figsize=(8, 6))
    
    # Use a loop to iterate over the columns and generate a pie chart for each one
    for i, question in enumerate(df.columns[1:], start=1):
        responses = df[question].value_counts()
    
    # Add a code cell to the Jupyter notebook
        code = 'ax[{}].pie(responses, labels=responses.index)\nax[{}].set_title("{}")'.format(i, i, question)
        notebook['cells'].append(nbf.new_code_cell(code))

    
    # Use nbconvert to convert the Jupyter notebook to a PDF file
    exporter = PDFExporter()
    pdf, _ = exporter.from_notebook_node(notebook)
    with open('{}.pdf'.format(sheet_name), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pdf)
```

Jupyter Note send me a pop-up window with title "Package Installation" and content [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYOQj.png):

The required file tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgf.sty is missing. It is a part of the following package: pgf. The package will be installed from.................

I click install, then it shows: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9PVu.png):

```
[I 14:00:51.966 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 4529aa41-ab04-45c9-ab04-a723aafffe41, name: python3
[IPKernelApp] CRITICAL | x failed: xelatex notebook.tex -quiet

Sorry, but C:\Users\EconUser\anaconda3\Library\miktex\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\xelatex.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/EconUser/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/xelatex.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

[I 14:02:52.109 NotebookApp] Saving file at /(Step By Step) Export PDF with texts, codes, and multiple plots.ipynb
```

I tried web browsing and followed the method in this guide: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/10910, but it did not work either.

I also try to install pandoc and MikTex again in Jupyter Notebook at the beginning of the code

```
!pip install --upgrade pip

!pip install pandoc
!pip install MikTex
```

it shows:
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\econuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandoc in c:\users\econuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ply in c:\users\econuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandoc) (3.11)
Requirement already satisfied: plumbum in c:\users\econuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandoc) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\econuser\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from plumbum->pandoc) (227)
**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MikTex (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MikTex**

I have no idea at all. **Is Miketex outdated or why**?

Comment: This isn't going to help you with your MikTex issue, but I wanted to point out that you should be using the magic command for installing using `pip install`. When installing in a notebook, use `%pip install <package name>`. See my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74770639/modulenotfounderror-in-python#comment131969319_74770639) for more about it and the comment right below for why use of the exclamation point is no longer best practice. Back to the `pip install MikTex` you tried ... `pip install <package>` only works for packages at the Python Package Index (PyPI).  (You...

Comment: <continued> can also use URLs or local packaged code if you point at a file but usually 'named' invocations like you tried have to be at PyPI. If you go to https://pypi.org/ and type in 'MikTex' you'll see that no package with that name comes up. (Contrast with searching 'pandas'.) Hence you cannot use `pip install MIkTex`. **And that is why you see `ERROR: No matching distribution found for MikTex`. There's no such package at PyPI.**

Comment: You seem to be using Anaconda/conda. Did you try running in your notebook `%conda install -c conda-forge miktex`? That command is based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/miktex). If you open a notebook and save as PDF from inside the GUI does it work? If it also complains than you should be running install with Jupyter notebook closed & running in the main terminal maybe? Also see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29616/what-is-the-preferable-setup-for-miktex-to-keep-all-packages-up-to-date-easily) for perhaps some helpful ideas if export PDF not working in Jupyter, too.

Comment: Thanks! Your first link has expired - it shows "Page not found. This question was voluntarily removed by its author." Do you know why?

Comment: I tried to run %conda install -c conda-forge miktex in my notebook. It is odd that it did not indicate any problems, but also did not generate any new notebook or pdf file.

Comment: Sorry about the dead link. It was a recent post with the information but apparently it got deleted. It happens. Sorry. I'll post a comment below with the info. About it not working after `%conda install -c conda-forge miktex` seemed successful. Did you try shut everything down and restart everything after? (I would think since you are using the API, it might have worked.) Also, just try `conda install -c conda-forge miktex` in the terminal (or in Anaconda if that is what you use) before even starting Jupyter and not in Jupyter.

Comment: The question I was linking to in my comment above, got deleted. Here's the information: `%pip install <package name>` is the current best practice, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic commands that insure that the installation occurs in the environment backing the notebook. Use of an exclamation point alone doesn't do this, more on that at the top [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez).